# Is there a way to check with python if a string from a list is a real word used in common English language?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract from a list of keywords just the words which are regular normal words in the English language.

Here is my code:

```
words = ['apple','a%32','j & quod','rectangle','house','fsdfdsoij','fdfd']
for word in words:
    if word ???: # How can I check if the words is a real word? Any module that I can use for that or a free API?
        print:
    else:
        pass
```

I would like to get as results only:

```
apple
rectangle
house
```

Comment: Try: http://www.datamuse.com/api/ - they are pretty good for English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First step, install nltk

Then:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')

from nltk.corpus import words

samplewords=['apple','a%32','j & quod','rectangle','house','fsdfdsoij','fdfd']

[i for i in samplewords if i in words.words()]

['apple', 'rectangle', 'house']
```